# Bxslider issue: Only one slide shown

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I'm having an issue using the bxslider. I'm trying to create a carousel of several images next to each other that slide by one each time the button is clicked. It appears the the `displaySlideQty` option is broken as only one slide is displayed at a time.

I'm trying to recreate this: http://bxslider.com/examples/display-move-multiple-slides-once-example-one

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tCeCe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not. Problem is elsewhere - in your style code

```
<div style="width:400px;">
    <ul id='slider' style="width:400px;">
```

Those two widths above *cannot* be the same - more specifically, your ul width needs to be way lower than the outside div width (otherwise you have the problem you described).

So change `<ul id='slider' style="width:400px;">` to a lower number, like `<ul id='slider' style="width:50px;">`

Comment: Thanks! I was playing around with the fiddle a little more an worked out that was the issue. I think the documentation should be a little more clear. The width of the <ul> *should be the same as the with of the <li>s* http://jsfiddle.net/tCeCe/2/